# Set picture Height depending on another picture height

Tags: javascript, height, getelementbyid

I'm trying to set the height of a picture (P2) depending on the height of another picture (P1) dynamically :

```
<script>
    function resizeElementHeight(element) {
        var P1 = document.getElementById('P1');
        var P2 = document.getElementById('P2');
        if(P1.height != P2.height) {
            P2.height = P1.height + "px";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Basically i wanna say "If the height of the picture P1 is different than the height of the picture P2, set the height of P2 the same as P1" but it doesn't work.

Could you please help me ? Thank you.

Comment: But, do you actually call the method when the DOM/image is ready/loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute) method, rather than `P2.height`. Same goes for `P1.height`, you must use [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) method.

So `P2.setAttribute('height', ... );`

Let me know if you need more guidance.

Comment: Do you mean like : if(P2.height != P1.height) {
    P2.setAttribute('height', P1.height + "px" );
}

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have the `height` attribute in your HTML, you can't get it like that. You would have to do something like this, if using pure JavaScript:

```
//<![CDATA[
var doc = document, bod = doc.body, IE = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split('MSIE')[1]);
bod.className = 'js';
function gteIE(version, className){
  if(IE >= version)bod.className = className;
}
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
function getPropertyFrom(p, e){
  return getComputedStyle(e).getPropertyValue(p) || e.currentStyle[p];
}
E('P2').style.height = getPropertyFrom('height', E('P1'))+'px';
//]]>
```

jQuery would be like:

```
//<![CDATA[
$('#P2').css('height', $('#P1').height()+'px');
//]]>
```

On a window resize, in pure JavaScript:

```
onresize = function(){
  E('P2').style.height = getPropertyFrom('height', E('P1'))+'px';
}
```

window resize in jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('#P2').css('height', $('#P1').height()+'px');
});
```

Note:
You should use external JavaScript, so it's cached. `window` in pure JavaScript is implicit so you don't need to write `window.onresize = function(){}`, `window.document`, `window.open()`, or the like. Just leave `window` out when referring to the `window` Object if you want.